# can powermock be used to test static methods

Tags: java, static, powermock

I have the following two classes:

```
public class Prod
{   
    public  void logon(){        
        System.out.println("'\u000CProd  logon");        
        addUser();        
    }
        public  void addUser(){     
        System.out.println("Prod  addUser");
    }
}

public class Dev extends Prod
{
    public void addUser(){     
       System.out.println("Dev  addUser");
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args){         
       Dev test = new Dev(); 
       test.logon(); 
    }   
}
```

Is there a way to make all the methods static and then test whether the Dev.addUser() is working correctly?

Here's what I would like to be able to do:

```
public class Prod
{   
    public static void logon(){        
        System.out.println("'\u000CProd  logon");        
        addUser();        
    }
        public static void addUser(){     
        System.out.println("Prod  addUser");
    }
}

public class Dev extends Prod
{
    public static void addUser(){     
       System.out.println("Dev  addUser");
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args){  
       logon(); 
    }   
}
```

When I run the main() in Dev we should get:

> Prod logon
>
> Dev addUser

Comment: Post the code with "all the methods static". What is the method you want to test? What is the class you want to mock? (I assume you want to mock something since you mention powermock)

Comment: Question is not clear, what do you want?

Comment: test.logon() will throw NullPointerExcpetion in 2nd case.... Can you explain your question a bit more.. For static methods you call them like Prod.logon()

Comment: @ketan, I agree your comment is not clear.  What don't you understand?

Comment: in the second example it should just say logon()

Comment: And what do you think you get from A) making things static to B) then be forced to use PowerMock(ito) in order to test things? Seriously, in the real world, that is the exact wrong direction. In the real world, you absolutely prefer non-static over static, and one reason for doing so: because you then can go with ordinary Mockito, instead of PowerMock(ito).

Comment: @GhostCat, there are many worlds and I assure you mine is as real as yours.  But seriously, we are teaching a class and have a large group project on static methods.  Was just looking for an easy way for students to test their answers.  They create class Dev, we supply them with a jar of Prod.  For direct methods they can just sub one method out for the other .  For methods that are called by other methods was looking to avoid writing specific test cases.  The project has 10 direct methods and 5 indirect or methods that are called by the first 10.

Comment: See my answer then: what you ask for doesn't work in Java. Honestly: a person who is about to teach students Java should know that. For now, I can't give more guidance than what I wrote in that answer. It is really unclear what exactly you intend to *test* here. One could test your code in many different ways. So, now that your "can I do that with static" has been answered ... feel free to accept an answer ;-) and maybe ask up a new more specific question of what you want to test. As said: in good designs there is no need for PowerMock. If you can't do it with Mockito, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Beyond that: teaching students to use *static* in such strange ways, and then telling them "and because *static* is such a deficient concept, we turn to the most dangerous chainsaw of mocking frameworks to somehow enable us to test our untestable design" is, again, wrong. You are about to teach **bad** practices. You are **not** doing your students a favour by going down that road.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept! Anything else I could add to also make the answer upvote worthy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to make all the methods static and then test whether the Dev.addUser() is working correctly?

No, there isn't.

This is really fundamental Java: you want to use static methods in a polymorphic context. But static methods are **not** polymorphic. There is no true inheritance, there is **no** over**writing** of static methods. See [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/258050/why-overriding-a-static-method-does-not-result-in-polymorphism-in-java) for lengthy explanations why that is. Repeat: the desired output can't be achieved in a purely static way, built around class A extending class B. End of story.

And as already said: this is also wrong from a conceptual point. Because of such restrictions, **static** should only be used carefully in Java. Simply go with the non-static code you have right now.

Unfortunately your question isn't really clear what exactly you intend to **test**, therefore I can't help with that part.